# Using Service Account For Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I wanted to create a web service like feature that would provide me the JSON response from the google analytics, i plan to do some processing on the GA data and then output the response to the user who would have requested for my service.

I selected PHP as my language and used **google-api-php-client** from google and now since i don't want to authorize every time to get Token, i thought of using Service account with which i would directly use keys.

I downloaded the sample code from [Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/prediction/serviceAccount.php) changed client ID and Service Account Name and Key location.

But then this Error Came

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to Google_HostedmodelsServiceResource::predict() 
must be an instance of Google_Input, none given, called in /var/www/webservice/GA/serviceanalytics.php 
on line 62 and defined in /var/www/webservice/GA/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PredictionService.php on line 36
```

I found that the second argument that example is passing should have been the third argument.

So what should be the second argument. A little insight or a working code will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Why would people pay you to see "your" google analytics data?   Wouldnt they rather see there own data?  With a service account the only data they have access to is yours.

Comment: Nah....it was for me... I was playing around with google API's.... I already created a web-app and now wanted to test the service account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you have posted [svn/trunk/examples/prediction/serviceAccount.php](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/prediction/serviceAccount.php)

Is for use with [Google Preditions api](https://developers.google.com/prediction/) If you have supplied a client ID and Service Account Name and Key location for an api that was set up to allow google analytics this wont work.  I sugest you look for an example using Google Analtyics or change the apis console to allow preditions api while you are getting to know the sample code for Google Preditions.

Comment: ohh..yeah, my bad....I was in a hurry and did a little copy paste. I am Sorry, that was stupid of me....I was supposed to use Google_AnalyticsService...

BTW thanks